# border layout with fixed regions with Compass & Sass?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am looking for the best way to achieve a traditional border layout with fixed regions (for example, a page with a fixed header and footer) and it looks like javascript layout engines are not the best way to go.  It's been a while since I've done css-based layout and I'm hoping CSS3/Sass/Compass make it a bit easier to achieve what was in the past somewhat difficult.

So I'm trying to create a fixed-header and footer border layout in Compass, is this easy or is there a better way (framework, language) to do it?  I am only targeting modern browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/uwcEw/

Not perfect but close I think.

Comment: any idea how to get the scrollbar in the "middle" div not to overlap (with content and overflow-y set to auto)  - I tried changing its z-index to a negative value but it is inaccessible then

Comment: Hard to get your question. Try to modify/fork that jsfiddle sample and show what you mean.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aCb7D/1/ - it's a bit trivial but i noticed it right away.  The top and bottom pixels on the scroll bar in the middle div overlay the border of the adjacent divs.  As compared to: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/complex.html, Which lays in the cut so to speak.  I put a negative z-index on the middle div and it solved the visual problem, however the middle div was no longer active.

Comment: Instead of percents you can use pixel lengths. This way you can make layout where elements will not overlap. My example is just an idea.
And yet: negative z-index there is a bad idea. You should rather use positive z-index values on border elements.

Comment: follow-up question thought maybe you could help again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159268/nested-border-layout-in-css