# Nested border layout in css?

Tags: css, layout, border-layout

I have this working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/uwcEw/ - a traditional border layout on css.

What I want to do is have another 5-region border layout within the "middle" of the border layout.  Re-applying the same pattern from above I get this: http://jsfiddle.net/6bked/4/ (**edited link**), which does not work, clearly it is not relative to it's parent container, but i'm not sure how to fix this so i can apply this pattern as needed in a nested context.

Any help?  Also if there's a better way to do this (Compass+Sass/blueprint/js layout) I'm open to suggestions.

**UPDATE**

I also wanted to make clear I only care about this working in modern browsers (Webkit, FF) mostly concerned with Webkit and I am not worried about users who don't have javascript enabled

Comment: what exactly that you want....

Comment: I want to do a border layout nested in the "middle" region of another border layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly the biggest fan of fixed layouts, but if I understand correctly this should be what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/8Cq9A/.

The dimensions are relative to the browser window, even the nested set of `div`'s. What you needed to do to fix your layout was adjust your inner dimensions taking that into account. For example if your outer left and right `div`'s widths are set to 10% *(meaning 10% of the width of the browser window)* to split the center `div` into 2 equal halves, you'd set each of their widths to: (100% - 10% - 10%) / 2 = 40%.

Personally, I'd look into using floats: http://jsfiddle.net/Sf8Kp/. The issue you will run into here though, is if you're wanting equal height columns as seen in the link.

There are **MANY** articles floating around on how to tackle this though. A few good reads that have been around for a while: alistapart ([1](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/), [2](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)), [positioniseverything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/). Search around for **faux columns** and **3 column [liquid|elastic|equal height] layout**.

Comment: To better explain this answer, the issue with using `position: fixed` is that the position is set relative to the browser window, not the containing element. Setting the position of your inner elements requires you to take this into account.

Comment: so, yes, The caveat to @anomareh's answer is that i need fixed heights and widths not percentages, thanks @Wex for clarifying - so basically i need to compute this at runtime using javascript or use a js layout lib?

Comment: @user445994 No the dimensions are still relative, just relative to the browser window. So for the nested div it still has relative dimensions, they're just relative to the browser like the parent and are in turn adjusted as such. I'll update the answer to explain better.

Comment: So, basically, css3 didn't help it's 2011 and we're still struggling to lay stuff out with css? ><  It seems like it's a lot easier to do this stuff with a javascript layout framework, but most purists say it's a bad idea though I'm not entirely sure why (other than dependencies)

Comment: I will fiddle around some more but I should have been more clear about 2 points:  the outer layout should be "fluid" or percentage based, while the inner layout, i want the top, bottom, left and right to be fixed while the middle is fluid- should i still be looking at floats?  thanks

Comment: also edited original to point out i only care about modern browser compatibility

Comment: @user445994 Yes. You can do what you just described in the second example I posted. Just plug in the values you want. All you have to do is set the top, bottom, left, and right inner `div`'s to what ever fixed width you want. Then just adjust the left and right margins of `#centerCenter` to be equal to what you changed them to. If you don't care about people with JS disabled and need equal height columns, it is trivial to write up a jQuery script to do so.